# Calculating tax owed with thresholds and rates in java

Tags: java, algorithm, methods

for a part of my revenue program I am making as an assignment for school I have to calculate a number which is the Total Tax Owed from a citizen. I am given in a text file the number of thresholds, the threshold value, and the rate at each threshold. An example is

```
Threshold   Rate
$15,000 15%
$29,000 20%
$50,000 25%
```

A citizen whose net income is $55,000 would pay:
$15,000*0%+$14,000*15%+$21,000*20%+$5,000*25% = $7,550

I have started my method here

```
private void computeTaxOwed(Citizen cit, TaxSchedule sked){

    double netIncome = cit.getNetIncome();
    double totTaxPaid = cit.getTotTaxPaid();

    int levels = sked.getNumLevels();
    double[] threshold = sked.getThreshold();
    double[] rate = sked.getRate();

    double taxOwd = 0;

    for(int i = levels; i>0; i--){
        taxOwd = ((netIncome-threshold[i])*rate[i]);
    }
```

I know this will not give the correct output and I just can't figure out how to make this algorithm work. If I could extract the values of both arrays and save them each to an individual variable I could easily get the right output but I think that is very messy and not the best way to do it.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Keep track of what portion of the income the citizen has yet to pay tax on, and update that every pass through the loop. There's your clue. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double netIncome = 55000;

        int levels = 3;
        double[] threshold = {0, 15000, 29000, 50000};
        double[] rate = {0, 15,20,25};

        double taxOwd = 0;

        double taxableIncome = 0;
        double netIncomeLeft = netIncome;

        for (int i = levels; i > 0; i--) {
            taxableIncome = netIncomeLeft - threshold[i];
            taxOwd += taxableIncome * (rate[i]/100);
            netIncomeLeft = threshold[i];
        }
        System.out.println("taxOwd " + taxOwd);
    }
}
```

or in a more compact fashion:

```
        for (int i = levels; i > 0; i--) {
            taxOwd += ((netIncome - threshold[i]) * (rate[i]/100));
            netIncome = threshold[i];
        }
```

Comment: Suppose the starting `netIncome` was 1,000.00, what would the `taxOwd` be? Looks like a refund to me!

Answer (score 3):

AlfaTek's suggested answer does not deal with the case that the rate in the 0-15000 bracket is nonzero, because i > 0 and not i >= 0 as the termination condition of his for loop.  The following snippet deals with this issue:

```
    double netIncomeLeft = netIncome;
    double taxOwd = 0;

    for (int i = threshold.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if(netIncomeLeft < threshold[i]) {
            //continue on if current tier is greater than the remainder
            continue; 
        }

        taxOwd += (netIncomeLeft - threshold[i]) * rate[i] / 100.0;
        netIncomeLeft = threshold[i];
    }
```